# vscode multiline regex for flat txt database

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, multiline

I am looking for a multiline search-replace regex for VScode that will find the first `\this line` in a txt file within sets of lines starting with `\begin` and `\end`. The textfile contains about 12000 sets of `\begin ...\end`.

One could say that these sets of `\begin .. \end` are records.
`\thisline` never occurs right after `\begin` or right before `\end`. There can however be about +500 characters between `\begin` and the first `\thisline`. The regex should not look beyond `\end` into the next set. If `\thisline` is found a

Example of text file

```
\begin
line 
line          /* there can be 20 lines or more here with +500 chars */
\thisline
line          /* there can be 20 lines or more here with +500 chars */
\thisline
line
line
line         /* there can be 20 lines or more here with +500 chars */
line
line  
\end

\begin
line
\thisline
line
line
\thisline
line
\end
```

I tried the following multiple line Find - replace:

```
(\\begin.*)
((.|\n|\r){1,100}?)
(\\this)(line.*)
((.|\n|\r){1,100}?)
(\\end.*)
```

Replace:

```
$1
$2
$4 changed $5
$6
$8
```

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/monbj.png)

The problem is how to find the last `\thisline`  in `\begin .. \end` sequences that have multiple `\thisline`(s)?

The second problem is how to keep the regex within the borders of the `\begin .. \end` records?

Comment: Regular expressions don't work well with recursion. Check this [regex.com demo based on your find/replace rules](https://regex101.com/r/1GTSqU/1) - I made the expression a bit simpler. You could use [lookaheads/lookbehinds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) but your expression will increasingly be harder to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If only vscode could be made to understand my data structure, that would be a solution. The regex can do the rest .....

Comment: Regex is still bad for handling a recursive structure and also several kB of text. There is also certainly a limit that the regular expression will capture. This is more a job for a small script that splits datasets into an array by the "\begin" marker.